# Probability of rolling a specific combination of results with nd6

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, anydice

So far I was able to figure out most things I needed to do in anydice on my own and with help of various posts in forums, however in this case my math knowledge fails me.

How do I calculate the probability to roll for example "1,1,1,1,1-4,1-4" with 7d6 and such? And how do I code that in anydice?

The problem is based on the Shadowrun dice pool. There if half or more of your dice are a 1 you "glitch" which is a bit more than just failing the test. Successes are counted on number of 5+'s in your pool. If you glitch but don't have any successes it's a critical glitch. So this is basically about the probability of getting a critical glitch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The problem is based on the Shadowrun dice pool. There if half or more of your dice are a 1 you "glitch" which is a bit more than just failing the test. Successes are counted on number of 5+'s in your pool. If you glitch but don't have any successes it's a critical glitch. So this is basically about the probability of getting a critical glitch.

Well, here's [a quick AnyDice script](https://anydice.com/program/17acd) to calculate the odds of that:

```
function: glitch ROLL:s {
  result: 2*[count 1 in ROLL] >= #ROLL & [count {5,6} in ROLL] = 0
}

output [glitch 7d6]
```

The way this works is that:

- The function `glitch ROLL:s` expects a sequence of numbers as a parameter.  (That's what the `:s` in the definition means.)  When given a dice pool like `7d6`, AnyDice automatically calls the function for every possible (sorted) sequence of numbers obtainable by rolling the dice, and sums up the results into a single biased die representing the probability of the function returning each of the possible results when called with a random dice roll.
- In the function, `2*[count 1 in ROLL] >= #ROLL` evaluates to true (1) if at least half the numbers in the sequence `ROLL` are ones, and to false (0) otherwise. Similarly, `[count {5,6} in ROLL] = 0` evaluates to true if there are no fives or sixes in `ROLL`, and to false otherwise.  The operator `&` between them is logical AND: it returns true (i.e. 1) only if both of the expressions around it are non-zero (i.e. not false).

So basically, there's no particularly fancy math here — AnyDice just solves the problem by brute force, testing every possible dice roll to see if it's a critical glitch or not.  (There's [a *little* bit of fancy math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) involved in calculating the probabilities of each *sorted* outcome of a 7d6 roll, but that all happens automatically behind the scenes.)

---

Ps. If you'd like to do this in Python instead, you could use e.g. the `dice_pool` function from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65440), which does the same thing that AnyDice does internally — it generates all possible sorted rolls of an *N*d*X* pool and their respective probabilities.  You could then just write a simple loop that sums up the probabilities of all the rolls that are critical glitches and outputs that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solution works perfectly and in the end it was easier to calculate than I realised.

Comment: Worth listing out the rough results for Xd6: `1: 17%`, `2: 19%`, `3: 5%`, `4: 5%`, `5: 1%`, `6: 1%`, `7+: <1%`.  Note that it is a funny result, even numbers have higher chances of failing than the odd number below them e.g.: `p(6) > p(5)`, `p(2) > p(1)`.